# Firefox extension implementing AngularJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to use "self.port.emit" in my angular service to send my add-on a result from the UI. The problem is I am not getting any errors so, I am not sure why the panel is not detecting the self.port.

Below is my current folder structure:

```
add-on/
    lib/
        toolbar.js
    data/ 
        angularApp/
            app/ 
            scripts/
                controllers/
                    groupCtrl.js
                services/
                    groupservice.js
```

In my gorupservice.js I have the following code:

```
angular.module('angularApp').service('groupservice'), function() {
    this.addGroup = function(name) {
        self.port.emit("newGroupName", name);
    }
}
```

The groupservice is called by the groupCtrl.js. The function addGroup is being called. In toolbar.js, I have a "self.port.on" listening for the "newGroupName". In toolbar.js, I have

```
function createSettingsPanel() {
     var settingsPanel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
         ...
         contentScriptFile: [data.url("angularApp/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js"),  
         data.url("angularApp/app/scripts/app.js"),
         data.url("angularApp/app/scripts/controllers/groupservice.js")],
     });

     settingsPanel.port.on("newGroupName", function() {
         console.log("MADE IT"); //NOT GETTING HERE!
     }); 
}
```

If anyone has any experience with angular.js in a Firefox add-on, the help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the content script(the angular app) use addon.port.emit instead of self.port.emit and it works.

Answer (score 0):

It's a shot in the dark, but should this code:

```js
angular.module('angularApp').service('groupservice', function() {
    this.addGroup = function(name) {
        self.port.on("newGroupName", name);
    }
}
```

be

```js
angular.module('angularApp').factory('groupService', function() {
    var groupService;

    groupService.addGroup = function(name) {
        self.port.emit("newGroupName", name);
    }

    return groupService;
}
```

You looking for a singleton right?

Some questions: is "self" a global variable? Is `self.port` defined when you inject the service?

Comment: self is essentially a variable used to communicate between the add-on and the content scripts. To send a message, self.port.emit is used and to receive the message use self.port.on.

Comment: does the change on my code make any difference? guess you are looking for a singleton that emits events, instead of receiving events?

Comment: Your code did the same thing as before. Still no errors.

Comment: `settingsPanel` is listening for changes, but you are emitting from `self`, is settingsPanel an instance of `self` (or even, the same object)? If not, you might want to setup your service with an instantiator so you can define where to start emitting events